# DevContainers started through WSL2 do not see environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2, vscode-remote

When starting the latest version of VSCode within a WSL2 (Ubuntu) shell running `code .`, then rebuilding/reopening a `.devcontainer.json` - the host environment variables are not recognized.

It is a pretty basic `.devcontainer.json`, nothing else is really being defined (variable-wise) and it has the `mounts` section.

This does **not** work:

```
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.m2/,target=/home/vscode/.m2/,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    ],
```

This works...

```json
    "mounts": [
        "source=/home/johndoe/.m2/,target=/home/vscode/.m2/,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    ],
```

It looked like this was something fixed recently in VSCode  but I still cannot get it to work.

- [Remote Containers with WSL2 Environment Variables Not Available](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3548)
- [Cannot use environment variables in containerized environment in WSL2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3086)